# $("header").load('header.html') not loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I tried looking for the answer for this simple question. I tried to use the answers that was posted but i still get some errors and my header is not being shown.

I have this code snippet :

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#header').load('partial/header.html'); 
    });
</script>
```

And my html body have this div :

```
<div id='header'></div>
```

I am getting the error that it cannot load the file "partial/header.html" with a message "Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource."

any help is welcome

Comment: Are you serving your page with an http server, or are you opening your static page directly from the filesystem?

Comment: Try absolute URL with `load`, ex. `http://localhost/name/...`

Comment: If you use the base property in the head tag, makevsure it has the propper value attached. With or without the WWW domain makes a big difference.

Comment: you are trying to open the page directly instead of putting it on some web server and loading it.

Comment: Try to prepend a slash like, `/partial/header.html`, this will indicate that you're fetching from a root, so it won't issue "Cross-origin" error

Comment: @Tushar and Susheel: my codes are still in my computer. I am not using any servers as this is just a simple html webpage. I do not see any reason to use servers at this time since my pages are just informational and no transactions.

dave: i tried prepending with "/" and it is still not working. I also tried changing the file from .html to .txt and it does not render. I to include the full path and it is still not being rendered.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and spend hours to find out a solution. And I found the answer there [Use JavaScript to Load Header and Footer Templates](https://iiiji.com/no-programming-needed-use-javascript-to-load-header-and-footer-templates-works-just-like-php-include/):

> This JavaScript works on a server environment, so this **will not be**
>   **able to load** header and footer if you are opening **the files from your**
>   **desktop** which means you need to upload your files via FTP and access
>   your HTMLs live.

So I installed **nodeJS with the http-server package** as described there [Local Web Server](https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2016/06/22/nodejs-setup-simple-http-server-local-web-server) and started server from the directory with index.html `http-server`.

Now I can see my header in the `http://localhost:8081/index.html` (8081 was shown in the console. Apparently my port 8080 is busy)

Also this should start with `/` :

```
$('#header').load('/partial/header.html');
```

I hope it will save the time for another js beginner.

Answer (score -1):

are you sure? I build a new page of "header.html", then copy your code, I can get the page and add it into the div of "header".

Comment: Not constructive at all

Comment: @Dorvalla He can't post comments with 9 reputation and he's very new to this site